# Make background of windows form transparent with a clean edge

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I'm making a winform (in c sharp) with an image in the middle and a timer that kicks people off after a certain time. I want to make the background of the form transparent so that the user sees just the image displayed with the timer. I've incorporated the transparency key that most folks seem to use. However the edge is jagged. Is there a way to accomplish this so that I'd have a "clean" edge? Or would I need to use a different approach?

Since I can't post images, here are direct links to what they look like
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4j4BevsH5aWdUVUYUhadzJRQlU/view?usp=sharing (what happens with transparencykey)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4j4BevsH5aWaUpIbVdSOVJGeVE/view?usp=sharing (smooth original picture)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you should just use an image with real transparency. Adding  alpha to a opaque image will *never* be perfect

Comment: *Winforms + real transparency = layered windows*

Comment: If you create 'smoothness' by semitransparent anti-aliased pixels you just can't use transparency key which works on/off: either equal and transparent or not equal and opaque.